Optimize select distinct value in hierarchical query
I need to find all the unique values of the field on which I do a hierarchical query.
I can just add select distinct name to my query, but it seems not optimal.
For example
select * from All_Dependencies AD 
connect by nocycle AD.Referenced_Owner = prior AD.Owner and AD.Referenced_Name = prior AD.Name and AD.Owner = 'SYS'
start with AD.Referenced_Owner = 'SYS' and AD.Referenced_Name = 'DUAL' and AD.Owner = 'SYS'

among the results I see
NAME                      REFERENCED_NAME    
ALL_SYNC_CAPTURE_TABLES   ALL_STREAMS_TABLE_RULES 
ALL_SYNC_CAPTURE_TABLES   ALL_STREAMS_TABLE_RULES

I think this means that Oracle having found the entire hierarchy headed by ALL_STREAMS_TABLE_RULES and stumbled upon it a second time, does not stop
and re-searches its entire hierarchy.
To fetch just all the names I don't need all the paths leading to the same result because then I use distinct.
Can it be optimized?
